# How to bond wireless networks?

Tags: wireless

Does anyone know how to bond wireless networks?

If so, please write a step by step howto.

I am new in Linux and I don't know anything.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing my experience with it so far: [Ubuntu 14.04 - Bonding 2 WIFI cards](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459687/ubuntu-14-04-bonding-2-wifi-cards).

No luck yet, but I'm probably not too far since the 2 wifi cards seem connected when running iwconfig.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit hard to describe here but you can refer to this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding) about how to bond Network in Ubuntu